# Python Multiprocessing.dummy Sockets Download Images

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, http, python-multithreading

I am using Python sockets to download images from a website. I am not interested in using the requests or urllib library. I would like to speed up this process with threading. I have used the multiprocessing.dummy library before and it has usually worked for me. In this case, it is very unpredictable. When it should be downloading 53 images (see the response headers below) it downloads anywhere from 38 to 44 usually. I have counted the number of response header messages and there are 53 of them. That seems to suggest that I am should receive 53 images. Yet, my code saves less than 53 images every time. Can anyone spot where I am making a mistake with my threads? I have downloaded all the images without utilizing threading and it worked perfectly. This is what leads me to believe that it is a problem with my threading implementation. Below is an example run of my script.

```
PS D:\Documents\School\RIT\Classes\Summer 2018\CSEC 380\Homework\3\Script> python .\hw3-script.py
MESSAGE SENT
GET /gccis/computingsecurity/sites/rit.edu.gccis.computingsecurity/files//xAcharya.jpg.pagespeed.ic.dQLJ0KfusA.jpg HTTP/1.0
Host: www.rit.edu
Accept: image/jpg, image/png


MESSAGE SENT
GET /gccis/computingsecurity/sites/rit.edu.gccis.computingsecurity/files//xAbuaitah.jpg.pagespeed.ic.PFwk87Pcno.jpg HTTP/1.0
Host: www.rit.edu
Accept: image/jpg, image/png


MESSAGE SENT
GET /gccis/computingsecurity/sites/rit.edu.gccis.computingsecurity/files/images/xCSEC.png.pagespeed.ic.Ep0KUkS94M.png HTTP/1.0
Host: www.rit.edu
Accept: image/jpg, image/png


MESSAGE SENT
GET /gccis/computingsecurity/sites/rit.edu.gccis.computingsecurity/files//xJake,P20Brown.jpg.pagespeed.ic.KvGLjuuU03.jpg HTTP/1.0
Host: www.rit.edu
Accept: image/jpg, image/png

<...many more MESSAGE SENT and RESPONSE HEADERS...>

RESPONSE HEADERS
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 12 Aug 2018 15:19:44 GMT
Server: Apache
Link: <http://www.rit.edu/gccis/computingsecurity/sites/rit.edu.gccis.computingsecurity/files/images/CSEC.png>; rel="canonical"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Expires: Mon, 12 Aug 2019 12:51:06 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Etag: W/"0"
Last-Modified: Sun, 12 Aug 2018 12:51:06 GMT
X-Original-Content-Length: 13647
Content-Length: 10131
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/png

RESPONSE HEADERS
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 12 Aug 2018 15:19:44 GMT
Server: Apache
Link: <http://www.rit.edu/gccis/computingsecurity/sites/rit.edu.gccis.computingsecurity/files/images/footer-logo.png>; rel="canonical"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Expires: Mon, 12 Aug 2019 14:09:08 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Etag: W/"0"
Last-Modified: Sun, 12 Aug 2018 14:09:08 GMT
X-Original-Content-Length: 19921
Content-Length: 16125
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/png

Number of image urls: 53
Number of files downloaded: 42
Time elapsed: 0:00:04.019662
```

My code:

```
import sys
import socket
import re
import os
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from datetime import datetime


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class MySocket:

    def __init__(self, sock=None):
        if sock is None:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        else:
            self.sock = sock

    def connect(self, host, port):
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

    def myclose(self):
        self.sock.close()

    def mysend(self, msg, debug=False):
        if debug:
            print("MESSAGE SENT")
            print(msg.decode())
        self.sock.sendall(msg)

    def myreceive(self, debug=False):
        received = b''
        buffer = 1
        while True:
            part = self.sock.recv(buffer)
            received += part
            if part == b'':
                break
        if debug:
            print("Received...")
            print(received)
        return received


def get_image_urls(html):
    """
    Gets all urls corresponding to images in given html data
    :param data: html page to parse
    :return: list of image urls
    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    img_urls = []
    for image in soup.find_all('img'):
        string = str(image)
        split = string.split("src=\"")
        if split[1][0] == '/':
            find_url = split[1].split("\"")
            url = find_url[0]
            img_urls.append(url)
            # img_urls.append("www.rit.edu" + url)
    return img_urls


def download_image(img_url):
    """
    Download images with the given socket and list of urls
    :param img_url: url corresponding to an image
    :return: None
    """
    image_socket = MySocket()
    image_socket.connect("www.rit.edu", 80)
    message = "GET " + img_url + " HTTP/1.0\r\n" \
              "Host: www.rit.edu\r\n" \
              "Accept: image/jpg, image/png\r\n\r\n"

    image_socket.mysend(message.encode(), debug=True)
    reply = image_socket.myreceive()
    headers = reply.split(b'\r\n\r\n')[0]

    print("RESPONSE HEADERS")
    print(headers.decode())
    print()

    image = reply[len(headers)+4:]
    img_name = str(len(os.listdir(".\\act1step2images"))) + img_url[-4:]
    f = open(os.path.join(".\\act1step2images", img_name), 'wb')
    f.write(image)
    f.close()


def download_images(image_urls, directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

    pool = ThreadPool(100)
    pool.map(download_image, image_urls)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


def main():
    start_time = datetime.now()

    host = "www.rit.edu"
    port = 80
    message = "GET /gccis/computingsecurity/people HTTP/1.0\r\n" \
              "Host: www.rit.edu\r\n" \
              "Accept: */*\r\n\r\n"
    part2_socket = MySocket()
    part2_socket.connect(host, port)
    part2_socket.mysend(message.encode())
    html = part2_socket.myreceive().decode()
    part2_socket.myclose()
    image_urls = get_image_urls(html)
    download_images(image_urls, ".\\act1step2images")
    print("Number of image urls:", len(image_urls))
    print("Number of files downloaded:", str(len(os.listdir(".\\act1step2images"))))

    print("Time elapsed:", datetime.now() - start_time)

main()
```